# Solution to turtle concept in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

This is my piece of code:

```
import turtle
def draw_square(some_turtle):
   for i in range(1,5):
     some_turtle.forward(100)
     some_turtle.right(90)

def draw_art():

    window = turtle.screen()
     window.bgcolor("red")
     brad = turtle.Turtle()

    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)
    for i in range(1,5):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)

    window.exitonclick()
```

And as output it is showing this message below:

```
C:\Users\adc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/adc/PycharmProjects/untitled/tur.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: also, this is not your code. Your code runs, but this has an indentation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.  First, you need to call `draw_art()` to kick things off.  Second, you want `turtle.Screen()` not `turtle.screen()` which is a different function that's not helpful in this situation.  Here's a rework of your code with the above changes and some style fixes:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(some_turtle):
    for i in range(4):
        some_turtle.forward(100)
        some_turtle.right(90)

def draw_art():

    brad = turtle.Turtle("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)

    for i in range(4):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

draw_art()

window.exitonclick()
```

[image]

If you still have a problem with this code, edit all the error messages verbatim into your post.